# Variable declaration with sed in cshell

Tags: shell, variables, sed, cut, csh

I'm trying to parse a lattice with grep and save the output in a variable in a cshell script. But somehow I always get the error message "Illegal variable name" when adding the `FILE_IN_B` variable. I tried different spacings after the variables name and also tried `$()` ,or `%.*` ,instead of sed to remove the last four letters but neither works in cshell. Also tried setting the declaration in `""`, to no avail. I'm really desperate here...

```
#!/bin/csh
set FILE_IN = file.ext
set SOURCE = home/Developer
set FILE_IN_B=`sed '/.\{4\}$//' >>> "$FILE_IN"`.lat
set REC = `grep -C 1 'I=11' "$SOURCE/Lattice/$FILE_IN_B" | cut -d ' ' -f 3 | cut -d= -f 2| sed 's/sp//'`
```

Comment: AFAIK, there is no `>>>` operator in C shell

Comment: Hm, i tried the same with `set FILE_IN_B = $FILE_IN | sed '/.\{4\}$//' ` but that didn't work either. Is there another way to go about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`csh` has some built-in variable manipulation, including one meant for extension removal:

```
% set FILE_IN=file.ext
% set FILE_IN_B="${FILE_IN:r}.lat"
% echo "$FILE_IN_B"
file.lat
```

If `sed` is required then `printf` can be used as the standard input, similar to portable `sh`:

```
% set FILE_IN=file.ext
% set FILE_IN_B=`printf %s "$FILE_IN" | sed 's/.\{4\}$//'`.lat
% echo "$FILE_IN_B"
file.lat
```

Comment: This is exactly what i needed! Thanks a lot.